# JFrame.setVisible(false) and Robot.createScreenCapture timing

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm trying to capture the screen without including my application's window.  To do this I first call setVisible(false), then I call the createScreenCapture method, and finally I call setVisible(true).  This isn't working however and I'm still getting my applications window in the screen capture.  If I add a call to sleep this seems to resolve the issue, but I know this is bad practice.  What is the right way to do this?

Code:

```
setVisible(false);
BufferedImage screen = robot.createScreenCapture(rectScreenSize);
setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Note: I've already tried JFrame.repaint() and JFrame.validate() without success.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater() and run the capture inside of the runnable passed as an argument? My guess is that the repaint performed to remove your application is performed right after the end of the current event in the AWT-EventQueue and thus invoking the call immediately still captures your window. Invoking the createCapture in a delayed event through invokeLater should fix this.

Comment: Disable your Windows effects and it will work like a charm, don't even need the invokelater

Comment: If you don't know in advance if animations (when minimizing and maximizing windows) are enabled, then you have no choice but to use the timer. It is evil only because it freezes the window for the user.

Comment: I don't understand.  What are Windows effects and how do I disable them?  As far as a timer is concerned I don't see how that is going to help either.  I simply need a way to impose an absolute order of events such that a window is actually hidden before the screen shot is taken.

Comment: Windows effects are animations performed by your OS when windows events occur. For example, when you minimize a window, instead of simply hiding the window, your OS might perform an effect "showing" the window going in your taskbar. This can take a few hundreds of milliseconds. On Windows, you can deactivate those effects by: right-click "Computer"-->Properties-->"(Advanced) System settings"-->Click "Settings" in the performance panel and disable "animate windows when minimizing and maximizing".

Comment: There's also the issue of what is BEHIND your JFrame which you are removing from the screen. The application behind needs to do a repaint in order to paint itself where your JFrame used to be. If that application is swapped out to disk by windows, then it can take MINUTES for it to refresh. Granted, this is the extreme case, but the point is that for some situations you'd like to ask windows whether all the applications have finished refreshing/repainting. I don't think such an api function exists.

Answer (score 1):

you have to delay this action by implements [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), for example

```
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;

public class CaptureScreen implements ActionListener {

    private JFrame f = new JFrame("Screen Capture");
    private JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    private JButton capture = new JButton("Capture");
    private JDialog d = new JDialog();
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    private JLabel l = new JLabel();
    private Point location;
    private Timer timer1;

    public CaptureScreen() {
        capture.setActionCommand("CaptureScreen");
        capture.setFocusPainted(false);
        capture.addActionListener(this);
        capture.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 50));
        pane.add(capture);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(pane);
        f.setLocation(100, 100);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        createPicContainer();
        startTimer();
    }

    private void createPicContainer() {
        l.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 500));
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(l,
                ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scrollPane.setBackground(Color.white);
        scrollPane.getViewport().setBackground(Color.white);
        d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        d.add(scrollPane);
        d.pack();
        d.setVisible(false);
        d.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {

            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                f.setVisible(true);
            }

            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
            }

            public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void startTimer() {
        timer1 = new Timer(1000, new AbstractAction() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        capture.doClick();
                        f.setVisible(false);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        timer1.setDelay(500);
        timer1.setRepeats(false);
        timer1.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("CaptureScreen")) {
            Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize(); // gets the screen size
            Robot r;
            BufferedImage bI;
            try {
                r = new Robot(); // creates robot not sure exactly how it works
                Thread.sleep(1000); // waits 1 second before capture
                bI = r.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(dim)); // tells robot to capture the screen
                showPic(bI);
                saveImage(bI);
            } catch (AWTException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void saveImage(BufferedImage bI) {
        try {
            ImageIO.write(bI, "JPG", new File("screenShot.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void showPic(BufferedImage bI) {
        ImageIcon pic = new ImageIcon(bI);
        l.setIcon(pic);
        l.revalidate();
        l.repaint();
        d.setVisible(false);
        //location = f.getLocationOnScreen();
        //int x = location.x;
        //int y = location.y;
        //d.setLocation(x, y + f.getHeight());
        d.setLocation(150, 150);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                d.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                CaptureScreen cs = new CaptureScreen();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Dang!  I was gonna' say that.  Guess I'll just have to up-vote.  ;)

Comment: In your code you are calling Thread.sleep from within the Event Queue.  That is exactly what I'm trying to avoid!

Comment: @Ryan :-) after this response, I have no interest in explaining why it only works following ....